# to get the next character in the string

Tags: java, string

please help me find the code for getting the next character in the string

for example:

**input** `string = "abcd"`

**output** `string = "bcde"`

I can able to iterate only one character at the time.

thanks in advance

Comment: Please improve your question -e.g. show what you have tried.

Comment: How do you know that the next character in the series will be "e"?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: you should create an array with all avaible characters in order, or something similar to tell java what is the next char to java

Comment: too bad java doesn't have a function like Haskells succ to do this - in Haskell you would do succ 'd' which gets e

Comment: @Katana24 yeah I can't imagine how many times you'd iterate over the String to do that.

Comment: "I can able to iterate only one character at a time."

Answer (score 3):

Get the ASCII of the last character in the String and increase the ASCII value by 1.

try this,

```
        String sample = "abcd";
        int value = (int) sample.charAt(sample.length() - 1); // here you get the ASCII value
        System.out.println("" +((value < ((int)'z')) ? sample.substring(1) + (char) (value + 1) : sample));
```

Comment: Dont forget to test if the last one is `z` then I guess the next char would be `a`

Comment: @newuser I believe you can only iterate over each character one at a time.  I also took this to mean once.

Comment: rather that adding one you could try : `new_val = 97+(value+1-97)%26`

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the question (although I like the answer).  My guess is that the op is looking for a solution that only touches each character in the string once and does not copy any memory.

Comment: @DavidCowden I guess "I can able to iterate only one character at the time." is pretty vague so the OP should clarify this point.

Comment: @Marc yeah agreed.  I just kinda assumed that's what he meant by adding that specification.

Comment: @DavidCowden I accept your point.

Comment: @newuser Well in your update your are not "looping" back to `a`. Since the OP didn't say anything about that it's fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add one to the *char* values:

```
char[] chars = "abcd".toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    chars[i] += 1;
}
String nextChars = new String(chars);
```